Rigid Foam as Vapour Barrier in Basement
I've recently decided to finish the basement in my home and am currently planning out a materials list. When it comes to the construction of my exterior walls I have a few questions. I've searched the forum and haven't found anything specifically related to my questions, so hopefully this isn't a duplicate post.
A few years back as I was renovating the rest of my house I slapped up some 1" thick XPS foamboard onto the unfinished exterior walls in order to get a little bit of insulation value. This layer is continuous from the main level subfloor down to the concrete slab. All edges and gaps were sealed with blue tuck tape and spray foam. For a little more context on the situation.. I live in quite a cold climate. I also very recently dug up and water proofed my foundation.
Now my original plan was the finish the basement using the existing fiberboard as a moisture barrier, 2x4 framing, R12 fiberglass insulation in the stud bays, and a 6mil poly vapor barrier to top it all off. I am also planning on using DMX 1-Step underlayment ran up to the exterior walls, and then placing my framing on top of it to allow for ample airflow.
There are a few potential problems I see with this plan.. First off I absolutely detest the idea of sealing poly in between every single joist cavity with acoustic sealant. Secondly, if this 1" foamboard acts as a vapor barrier I could be trapping moisture inside of the wall.
So my questions are:
Would this 1" foamboard be a sufficient thermal break to stop moisture from condensing on the inside if I was to forego installing a poly vapour barrier?
If not, would an additional 1" foamboard glued onto the face of the existing one act in a sufficient manner for me to avoid using a poly vapor barrier at all?
As moisture slowly comes up through the slab underneath the DMX underlayment, would it be detrimental to have foamboard acting as a vapor barrier directly on the exterior wall so as to not allow the moisture to dry to the foundation?
Please feel free to ask me for any more details and let me know what you think.
